# How to create a Windows Server 2008 VM

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, virtual-machines, vmware-player

I have Windows 2008 Server set up. I want to create a Virtual machine with O/S Windows 2008 Server which can be booted with VM player. How do i go about it?

Thanks,
gauls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VMware Player is great way to test out new OSs!  Your basic steps are create a VM (an empty 30GB disk is good for server 2k8), get either a 2k8 disk or .ISO to mount, with the disk in the tray or the .ISO mounted start the player.  The install should begin.  For the VMware documentation check out:

1)http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vmware_player310.pdf
2)http://www.vmware.com/pdf/GuestOS_guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You need to use VMware Workstation, or VMware Server to create a new VM.  The VM Player can only be used to run an already created VM.  VMware Server is a free download from the VMware website.

Comment: The most recent version of VMware Player can also be used to create VM's.

Comment: Just create a new VM , insert the install disk or mount the .ISO, start the VM in VMware Player, watch the install start.  VMware player is a great free hobbiest way to try out both virtualization via a type 2 hypervisor and test other OSs in a non destructive manner/ w/o dual boot.

Comment: Also VMware Server is EOL, VMware player is the free replacement and workstation is the paid version.  Both do away with the browser UI and go with the virtualbox approach.

Answer (score 0):

The VMware vCenter [Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) works well too.